# Font awesome icon name

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Does anyone know name of this icon in fontawesome(ignore color)?

[image]

Comment: First. This is not a coding question. Second, are you sure it's fontAwesome ? Third, you could make it yourself in svg. Or use 2 square icons. Or you can find it on the web searching for ' clone square icon ' .

Comment: Ofc, it's not a coding question. I have many icons in my app. All of them are implemented with fontawesome, but only this one is left.

Comment: Ask your designer where did he get that icon. I don;t think it's font awesome. If you have access to the design you can ' export as svg ' and use it. Or you can find it on the web -> example : https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/icon/467935

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a coding question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This icon is called "clone".

See [this link](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/clone).

Comment: It's similar but not correct. :(